# Wispr-Location-Id and Wispr-Location-Name saved when accounting

Tags: freeradius, wispr

I have several Hotspots around the city, each one with different Wispr-Location-Id and Wispr-Location-Name. All these Hotspots use the same Radius server and share the same database.

Is there any way when accounting message is received to save this two parameters (Wispr-Location-Id and Wispr-Location-Name)

I need to know which clients roams from one Hotspot to another.
Thanks!

Comment: Which version of FreeRADIUS are you using?

Comment: Hi, I am using FreeRADIUS Version 2.2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to edit the queries specific to your database dialect:

They can be found at `/etc/(raddb|freeradius)/sql/<dialect>/dialup.conf`

https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v2.x.x/raddb/sql/mysql/dialup.conf#L163

You'll need to add the additional fields and values to the following queries:
- `accounting_start_query`
- `accounting_stop_query`
- `accounting_stop_query_alt`

an example of a modified `accounting_start_query` for MySQL would be:

```
accounting_start_query = " \
      INSERT INTO ${acct_table1} \
        (acctsessionid,    acctuniqueid,     username, \
         realm,            nasipaddress,     nasportid, \
         nasporttype,      acctstarttime,    acctstoptime, \
         acctsessiontime,  acctauthentic,    connectinfo_start, \
         connectinfo_stop, acctinputoctets,  acctoutputoctets, \
         calledstationid,  callingstationid, acctterminatecause, \
         servicetype,      framedprotocol,   framedipaddress, \
         acctstartdelay,   acctstopdelay,    xascendsessionsvrkey,
         wisprlocationid,  wisprlocationname) \
      VALUES \
        ('%{Acct-Session-Id}', '%{Acct-Unique-Session-Id}', \
         '%{SQL-User-Name}', \
         '%{Realm}', '%{NAS-IP-Address}', '%{NAS-Port}', \
         '%{NAS-Port-Type}', '%S', NULL, \
         '0', '%{Acct-Authentic}', '%{Connect-Info}', \
         '', '0', '0', \
         '%{Called-Station-Id}', '%{Calling-Station-Id}', '', \
         '%{Service-Type}', '%{Framed-Protocol}', '%{Framed-IP-Address}', \
         '%{%{Acct-Delay-Time}:-0}', '0', '%{X-Ascend-Session-Svr-Key}',\
         '%{WISPR-Location-Name}', '%{WISPR-Location-ID}')"
```

You'll also need to add additional string type columns in the `radacct` table to hold the additional values.